# How to solve chraracter encoding problems

Tags: linux, encoding, mysql, typo3, scp

i have two servers with TYPO3 installed on them. One is the testserver, one is supposed to be the liveserver. On the testserver, everything runs perfectly. 
When i create a mysqldump and copy it to the liveserver (with scp) all Umlauts are converted into sth. like 'ÐÒ§ÑÑÐ° Ð±ÑÐ·ÑÓÐ° (i looked with the nano editor at it). This happens **before** I import it into the database.

Can anyone give me a hint, how to fix this problem?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most important is to make sure, that your content tables are encoded properly (like `pages`, `tt_content` or extensions tables)

If only `static_languages` table has broken encoding that's no problem (*nota bene I just realized, that I have exactly same values ;) 'Ð~PÒ§Ñ~AÑ...* )

The static data are inserted by TYPO3 and if you'll lost the data you can recreate them easily - then, most probably it will insert values with correct encoding, just:

- go to the `Extension Manager (EM)`
- go into `Static Info Tables` ext
- select `Database Update` tab,
- select all checboxes under `Import static data`
- click `Make updates.`

**Edit:** Seems like your system is not completely set up for UTF-8. Latin1 only supports european languages (with accents & umlauts), however neither Chinese nor Cyrillic.

http://typo3-media.com/blog/article/utf8-and-typo3-updated.html

Comment: Hmm.. this worked fine for languages such as francais and espanol (The are displayed correctly now (in language_select). But for Russian und chinese, this didn´t seem to work. If I do a select on static_languages I get ??? for these languages. PS: Is it possible to append a screenshot?

Comment: I don´t understand why this works for some languages, but not for all. Any idea?

Comment: Seems like your system is not completely set up for UTF-8. Latin1 only supports european languages (with accents & umlauts), but not Chinese und Cyrillic. http://www.typo3-media.com/blog/article/utf8-and-typo3-updated.html